# VBScript - Create text file using folder name during loop

Tags: vbscript

Problem:
This script below is looping through 4+ million files and retrieving file property information to determine what can be purged.  The current process is already using 20+GB of RAM and is only half finished.

I've been creating a large batch file to write each subfolders contents to a new text file.  This isn't practical because its time consuming and this is the first of several servers that I will be running this process on.

Questions:
-Is it possible to create a new file to write to based on the subfolder loop? (using the object property in place of the file doesn't appear to do the trick)
-Or is is possible to write the contents to the file, then clear the previous data from my temporary memory?

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
objStartFolder = "C:\Test"

Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(objStartFolder)
Set colFiles = objFolder.Files

For Each objFile in colFiles
    On Error Resume Next 
    If Err Then
        MyFile.Write "Error accessing " & objFile & ": " & Err.Description & vbCrLf
        Err.Clear
    Else
        Q="""" 'Wrap quotes around string
        strFilePath = Q & objFile.Path & Q
        strFileName = Q & objFile.Name & Q
        strFileSize = objFile.Size
        strFileType = Q & objFile.Type & Q
        strFileDateCreated = objFile.DateCreated
        strFileDateLastAccessed = objFile.DateLastAccessed
        strFileDateLastModified = objFile.DateLastModified
        Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:")
        Set objFileSecuritySettings = _
        objWMIService.Get("Win32_LogicalFileSecuritySetting=""" & replace(objFile,     "\", "\\") & """")
        intRetVal = objFileSecuritySettings.GetSecurityDescriptor(objSD)
        If intRetVal = 0 Then
            strFileOwner = Q & objSD.Owner.Domain & "\" & objSD.Owner.Name & Q
        Else
            strFileOwner = Q & "Couldn't retrieve security descriptor." & Q
        End If

'               CreatedDiff = DateDiff("yyyy",strFileDateCreated,Now)
'               AccessedDiff = DateDiff("yyyy",strFileDateLastAccessed,Now)
'               ModifiedDiff = DateDiff("yyyy",strFileDateLastModified,Now)
'               MaxTime = 3 'Max time in years. For days change "yyyy" to "d"

'               If (CreatedDiff >= MaxTime) AND (AccessedDiff >= MaxTime) AND     (ModifiedDiff >= MaxTime) Then

            MyFile.Write strFilePath & "~|~" &_
            strFileName & "~|~" &_
            strFileSize & "~|~" &_
            strFileType & "~|~" &_
            strFileDateCreated & "~|~" &_
            strFileDateLastAccessed & "~|~" &_
            strFileDateLastModified & "~|~" &_
            strFileOwner & vbCrLf
'           End If
    End If
Next

ShowSubfolders objFSO.GetFolder(objStartFolder)

Sub ShowSubFolders(Folder)
    For Each Subfolder in Folder.SubFolders
    On Error Resume Next
        Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(Subfolder.Path)
        Set colFiles = objFolder.Files

    For Each objFile in colFiles
    On Error Resume Next 
    If Err Then
        MyFile.Write "Error accessing " & objFile & ": " & Err.Description & vbCrLf
        Err.Clear
    Else
        Q="""" 'Wrap quotes around string
        strFilePath = Q & objFile.Path & Q
        strFileName = Q & objFile.Name & Q
        strFileSize = objFile.Size
        strFileType = Q & objFile.Type & Q
        strFileDateCreated = objFile.DateCreated
        strFileDateLastAccessed = objFile.DateLastAccessed
        strFileDateLastModified = objFile.DateLastModified
        Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:")
        Set objFileSecuritySettings = _
        objWMIService.Get("Win32_LogicalFileSecuritySetting=""" & replace(objFile, "\", "\\") & """")
        intRetVal = objFileSecuritySettings.GetSecurityDescriptor(objSD)
        If intRetVal = 0 Then
            strFileOwner = Q & objSD.Owner.Domain & "\" & objSD.Owner.Name & Q
        Else
            strFileOwner = Q & "Couldn't retrieve security descriptor." & Q
        End If

'               CreatedDiff = DateDiff("yyyy",strFileDateCreated,Now)
'               AccessedDiff = DateDiff("yyyy",strFileDateLastAccessed,Now)
'               ModifiedDiff = DateDiff("yyyy",strFileDateLastModified,Now)
'               MaxTime = 3 'Max time in years. For days change "yyyy" to "d"

'               If (CreatedDiff >= MaxTime) AND (AccessedDiff >= MaxTime) AND (ModifiedDiff >= MaxTime) Then

            MyFile.Write strFilePath & "~|~" &_
            strFileName & "~|~" &_
            strFileSize & "~|~" &_
            strFileType & "~|~" &_
            strFileDateCreated & "~|~" &_
            strFileDateLastAccessed & "~|~" &_
            strFileDateLastModified & "~|~" &_
            strFileOwner & vbCrLf
'               End If
    End If
Next   
ShowSubFolders Subfolder
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: With so much data to be stored, are you sure a text file is your best option? Have you considered using a database? Also `On Error Resume Next` clears the `Err` object. So your `If Err Then` test will always be `False`.

Comment: Thank you for your input. In regards to your question regarding storing directly to a database, eventually I will be loading these files into a MySQL database.  However, with my limited VBScript knowledge I choose to opt for the two step approach. Any input or advice you may have would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit difficult to tell you how to do it since you've not provided your full script, as you reference objects that were not instantiated in the code you provided.

Yes you can write each folder's output to a new file as well as free memory. You need to change your script's structure a bit though. I was doing it for you until I came across more undefined objects and gave up, so instead I'll just tell you what to do.

You don't need two subs, just one will do. Here's the outline of the structure:

```
Dim fso, startfolder
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

startfolder = "C:\temp"
GetFileInfo startfolder

Sub GetFileInfo(folderpath)
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim file, logpath, logfile, folder
    logpath = "C:\log\" & fso.GetBaseName(folderpath) & ".log" ' C:\log folder must exist; but of course edit path and file name conventions as desired
    Set logfile = fso.OpenTextFile(logpath, 2, True)
    If Err Then EchoAndQuit "Failed to create log " & logpath & ": " & Err.Description

    ' Write the file info in current folder
    For Each file In fso.GetFolder(folderpath).Files
        logfile.WriteLine file.Name ' file/security info
    Next

    'Set x = Nothing (Set objects instantiated in this sub to nothing to release memory)

    ' Now the recursive bit
    For Each folder In fso.GetFolder(folderpath).SubFolders
        GetFileInfo(folder.Path)
    Next

    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub


Sub EchoAndQuit(msg)
    MsgBox msg, 4096 + 16, "Failed"
    WScript.Quit
End Sub
```

One problem with this is you'll get an access denied error if you have multiple folder with the same name - I'll leave it to you to work out some check/naming convention to avoid this. (You could get around it by setting logfile = nothing, but you'll overwrite existing log files if there are multiple folders with the same name. So that's something you could work out, some log file check/naming convention to get around the duplicate name issue, then you could destroy the object if you wanted.)